# Deploy CRM plugin to Zendesk

Tags: zendesk

I have a CRM plugin which I can deploy to Salesforce and it works fine.

My plugin is SPA which is written on javascript with durandal framework and it uses such libraries as knockout.js, require.js, q.amd.js, jquery.js, underscore.js, i18next.js and a few other javascript libraries. Is it possible to deploy such kind of app to Zendesk environment?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately, up to the moment **no**. There is an "ongoing" discussion on [Zendesk Support Forums](https://support.zendesk.com/hc/communities/public/posts/203460226-External-JavaScript-Files-in-Lotus-Apps) about the matter, but it looks like it's not going to happen anytime soon. Product managers interacted in the thread expressing *some* will to do it, but I wouldn't rely on that happening in a near future:

> *At the moment we have no plans to support external libraries. We may open this up to a select few in the future.*

Comment: You should check out ngDesk instead as its totally free and has awesome features. You can check it out here https://www.ngdesk.com